# Counting the number of times a number comes up

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I would like to count all possible combinations of each number from my table.

I would like my query to return something like this:

```
Number (Value)     Count
       1            39
       2            450
       3            41
```

My table looks like this:

[image]

When I run the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.LottoDraws ld
JOIN dbo.CustomerSelections cs
ON ld.draw_date = cs.draw_date

CROSS APPLY(
  SELECT COUNT(1) correct_count
  FROM (VALUES(cs.val1),(cs.val2),(cs.val3),(cs.val4),(cs.val5),(cs.val6))csv(val)
  JOIN (VALUES(ld.draw1),(ld.draw2),(ld.draw3),(ld.draw4),(ld.draw5),(ld.draw6))ldd(draw)
  ON csv.val = ldd.draw WHERE ld.draw_date = '2013-07-05'
)CC
ORDER BY correct_count desc
```

I get something like this:

[image]

Comment: you did't apply ld or cs outer table filter in cross apply clause . i think that is the problem . still i am not clear about your requirement .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I offer this solution because `unpivot` often performs better than a series of `union all`s.  The reason is that each `union all` can result in a full table scan whereas the `unpivot` does its work with a single scan.

So, you can write what you want as:

```
select val, count(*)
from (select pk, val
      from test
      unpivot (val for col in (val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6)
              ) as unpvt
     ) t
group by val
order by val;
```

Comment: Simple and effective: awesome answer

Answer (score 4):

Assuming I did understand correctly your needs, I solved the problem in the following way.
My assumptions are that you need to count the number of occurrencies a single value appears on either val columns (val1,val2,val3,etc..) indifferently.

this is my test data:

```
CREATE TABLE Test(
pk int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
val1 int, val2 int, val3 int, val4 int, val5 int, val6 int
)

INSERT INTO Test
SELECT 1,2,3,4,5,6 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,2,3,4,5,6 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,2,3,4,5,6 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,2,3,4,5,6 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,3,3,3,3,3 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,2,3,4,5,7
```

And this is the query returning the count of single val occurrencies:

```
SELECT v, SUM(c) FROM (
    SELECT val1 v, COUNT(*) c FROM Test GROUP BY val1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT val2 v, COUNT(*) FROM Test GROUP BY val2 UNION ALL 
    SELECT val3 v, COUNT(*) FROM Test GROUP BY val3 UNION ALL 
    SELECT val4 v, COUNT(*) FROM Test GROUP BY val4 UNION ALL 
    SELECT val5 v, COUNT(*) FROM Test GROUP BY val5 UNION ALL 
    SELECT val6 v, COUNT(*) FROM Test GROUP BY val6
 ) T
GROUP BY v
```

Results in my test case are:

```
val occurrencies
1   5
2   5
3   11
4   5
5   5
6   4
7   1
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I am missing something in the requirements, but I don't see a need to complicate with table value constructors and `CROSS APPLY`. Simple `UNION ALL` and `GROUP BY` can do the job.

```
SELECT V, COUNT(*) FROM 
(
    SELECT val1 v FROM dbo.CustomerSelections
    UNION ALL
    SELECT val2 FROM dbo.CustomerSelections
    UNION ALL
    SELECT val3 FROM dbo.CustomerSelections
    UNION ALL
    SELECT val4 FROM dbo.CustomerSelections
    UNION ALL
    SELECT val5 FROM dbo.CustomerSelections
    UNION ALL
    SELECT val6 FROM dbo.CustomerSelections
) x
GROUP BY v
```

PS: This is very similar to other answer, just it's somewhat better in performance terms to do union all first, then group by once.

Comment: Why? because if you play the lotto numbers `1,2,3,4,5,6` and the draw is `6,5,4,3,2,1` - I have clearly won the jackpot asking SQL to check val1 from my ticket table and comparing it to val1 in the draw table would clearly be wrong. My question is simply trying to find out how often a particular number comes up.